# How does the compiler understand whether the given function does a pass by value or pass by referene?

Tags: c, compiler-construction, reference, arguments

How does the C compiler understand whether the given function does a pass by value or pass by reference? 
what will happen if the pointer of a variable is passed as integer (as pass by value) to a function ? OR is this possible in C ?

ie: the address of a variable is copied to another variable(int) and that variable is passed to a function. here the called function will get an address as normal integer parameter. Is this possible in C? if not why?

Comment: `pass by reference` is not in `C`.Only pass by value is there.

Comment: Like @Jayesh says, there's only pass-by-value in C. You can *emulate* pass-by-reference by passing a pointer, but then the pointer is passed by value (that's why you need to pass a pointer to a pointer, if you want to change the pointer).

Comment: +1 for _that's why you need to pass a pointer to a pointer, if you want to change the pointer_.

Comment: `the address of a variable is copied to another variable(int) and that variable is passed to a function. here the called function will get an address as normal integer parameter` - it is pass by value. you are passing address as a value to a function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How does the C compiler understand whether the given function does a
>   pass by value or pass by reference?

For your information `C` not understand about *pass by reference*. You can send pointer to variable.

> what will happen if the pointer of a variable is passed as integer (as
>   pass by value) to a function ?

Passing the pointers to a variable and the accessing it using dereferencing within the function.So  By passing a pointer to a function you can allow that function to read and write to the data stored in that variable.

For example

```
void myfunc( int *myval ) // pointer "myval" point address of "locvar"
{
   *myval = 77; //place value 77 at address pointed by "myval"
}
int main()
{
    int locvar=10; //place value 10 at some address of "locvar"
    printf("locvar = %d\n",locvar);
    myfunc(&locvar);    // Here address of "locvar" passed 
    printf("locvar = %d\n",locvar);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In C it is possible only the pass by value (by reference is supported only in C++).

Both a standard variable and a pointer variable are passed by value. So, the compiler must not make any check about reference or value.

standard variables and pointer variables are same, both store values, but a pointer variable can store only an address value and supports the dereferencing operator '*', this operator get the value pointed by the pointer variable.

Thanks to this, when you pass by value (C support only by value) a pointer variable, the value of the pointer variable is copied in a local pointer variable (instanced in the function stack) this variable is the pointer argument of the function. So you can access to address value copied in the local pointer variable using the dereferencing operator.

**Added comments 08/22/14**

I can better explain with a example:

```
void FuncSet10(int* PtrArgument)
{
    // The PtrArgument is a local pointer variable
    // it is allocated in the stack. The compiler
    // copies the MyIntVariable address in this variable

    // Using dereferencing operator I can access to
    // memory location pointed by PtrArgument
    *PtrArgument = 10;


}

void FuncSet20(int IntArgument)
{
    // The IntArgument is a local variable
    // allocated in the stack. The compiler
    // copies the MyIntVariable address in this variable

    // this code emulates the dereferencing operator
    // and so poiter mechanism.
    *((int*)IntArgument) = 20;
}

void FuncMovePointer(int* pointer)
{
    int a = *pointer++;  // now a contains 1
    int b = *pointer++;  // now b contains 2
    int c = *pointer++;  // now c contains 3

    printf("a contains %d\n", a);
    printf("b contains %d\n", b);
    printf("c contains %d\n", c);

    // The *Ptr now points to fourth (value 4) element of the Array
    printf("pointer points to %d\n", *pointer);
}


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

    int Array[] = {1, 2, 3, 4}; // Array definition
    int* pointer = Array;       // pointer points to the array

    int MyIntVariable;

    // First example for explanation of
    // the pointer mechanism and compiler actions

    // After calling this function MyIntVariable contains 10
    FuncSet10(&MyIntVariable);

    printf("MyIntVariable contains %d\n", MyIntVariable);

    // After calling this function  MyIntVariable contains 20
    // This code emulate pointer mechanism
    FuncSet20((int)&MyIntVariable);

    printf("MyIntVariable contains %d\n", MyIntVariable);

    // Second example to demonstrate that a pointer
    // is only a local copy in a called function

    // Inside function the pointer is incremented with ++ operator
    // so it will point the next element before returning by function
    // (it should be 4)
    FuncMovePointer(pointer);

    // But this is not true, it points always first element! Why?
    // Because the FuncMovePointer manages a its local copy!

    printf("but externally the FuncMovePointer it still points to first element %d\n", *pointer);

    return 0;
}
```

I hope that above code can help better your understanding.

Angelo

Comment: but then, an int 10 also will be passed as value to a function. and the function can treat it as a pointer? there should be some mechanism in C compiler to identify both right?

Comment: I added new comment and code in my post. Please read it and if it clarifies better the pointer mechanism you can make post as answered. Thanks!